# How to run tests from a test-jar in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I have a multi project build in gradle. In project `gradle-playground-a` I'm creating a test-jar with some junit tests:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test.enabled = false

configurations {
    testArtifacts.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "test"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
artifacts {
    testArtifacts testJar
}
```

Now I would like to run the tests of the test-jar within another project `gradle-playground-b`. Therefore I have:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testRuntimeOnly project (path: ":gradle-playground-a", configuration: 'testArtifacts')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

However the tests from the test-jar are not run. When I look at gradles debug output I see that the test-jar is included in the classpath for the test execution of `gradle-playground-b`.

What I'm trying to do is to have an equivalent of [mavens surefire `depednenciesToScan`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan) functionality.

How do I execute the tests from the test-jar when testing `gradle-playground-b`?

Answer (score -3):

I just use a "button" in netbeans on the first project to activate the second project.  That's the only way I really know how to do it because I have done sortof limited projects I am pretty sure you could do this in VB with Visual STudio but since your in Java use netbeans and it's free.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using plain gradle from the command line. This doesn't seem to help me.